# Laravel Request Class prepareForValidation not reflected in $request->get

Tags: laravel, laravel-9, laravel-request, laravel-octane, octane

In a API endpoint taking "emails" as an array, I am validating values with a Request Class. In this Request class' prepareForValidation method:

```
$this->merge([
    'emails' => array_unique($this->emails)
]);
```

I have this lines. And a controller like this:

```
foreach ($request->get('emails') as $email) {
    //process
}
```

In local environment, I have no error or bug. It works expected. I am giving "aaa@bbb.com" twice, and it works only once. But in server (with octane, no other changes), when I give "aaa@bbb.com" twice again, it works twice.

I have finally solved the problem with using

```
$request->input()
```

instead of "$request->get()". But I am curious, why $request works fine in local but causing problems in server? Is it related to Octane? Has anyone encountered such a problem before?

Comment: Is this a json request? are you running it exactly the same production / local

Comment: @mrhn Not "exactly", local on mac valet and server in ubuntu nginx. But not mentionable differences. Same db, same tools. Only difference is Octane. Yes, JSON request.

Comment: @lagbox thank you for your helpful comment. But I still cannot understand why its working as expected without octane in local. Interesting situation

Comment: sorry I need to correct that comment ... `get` has a different priority of which input bags it will check first compared to `input` (not that it only checks the query parameters, i was thinking of the `query` method), when dealing with validation it uses `input` to get the inputs [you want to be using the `input` method for dealing with inputs instead of `get`].... I will think on the implications of octane though for your situation